# Android NDK to use Multi-core cpu

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, multicore, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

How can I write C++ code to take advantage of multi-core cpu using android NDK (ice-cream-sandwich) or is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The same way you'd write a multi-threaded application for most other platforms - with [POSIX threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

A good place to start is probably [pthread_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

Comment: I wouldn't use pthreads directly on any platform if I could help it; I'd use an abstraction like [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/) instead.

Comment: @ildjarn - what other option do you have on Android? Only thread API on Android is POSIX threads, and that is C API. All other API (like Boost.Thread) is just a wrapper over POSIX threads.

Comment: @Mārtiņš : Right, hence "abstraction".

Comment: wrapper layer = more bugs/limitations (think MFC). Nothing wrong with using the real interface.

Comment: Abstraction or not, but all other choices, including Boost.Thread, involve calling C API from C++. So I see no reason to not to like using C libraries from C++. Following your logic - I should not be using OpenGL in C++, because it is C API.

Comment: Once I have it running is there a way too see if it in deed running on other cores? I am trying to get a game written in c/c++ to run faster on a multi-core cpu. do you know a good tutorial on this. thank again.